# Error while calling _search API in Elasticsearch on an index

Tags: elasticsearch, botocore

I am using botocore's AWSRequest to make calls to Elasticsearch cluster. I am using GET method on an index with _search API as follows:

```
req = AWSRequest(method=method, url=proto + host + urllib.parse.quote(path), data=payload,
                 headers={'Host': host, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

path is in the following format:

```
/<Document-Index>/_search?q=param:param-val
```

I am using:

```
SigV4Auth(creds, 'es', region).add_auth(req)
http_session = URLLib3Session()
res = http_session.send(req.prepare())
```

to make the GET call to the Elastic search endpoint.
I am getting the foillowing error:

```
Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/<Document-Index>/_search?<query_terms>] and method [GET], allowed: [POST]",
status: 405
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: looks like its a POST method call while you are making a GET method call as mentioned in error msg `and method [GET], allowed: [POST]`, can you try changing it ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your request url is not correct, print it somewhere and check.  I observed exact same error when  request url is - `GET test_index` instead of `GET test_index/_search` from Kibana.